# Syncing calendar events between Samsung Galaxy J3 V and Motorola Moto G Power

Tags: samsung, calendar, motorola-moto-g

My wife and I had Samsung Galaxy J3 Vs for several years. She still has hers (and loves it), but mine was accidentally destroyed last week, and I just got a new Motorola Moto G Power.

When we both had J3Vs, EVERYTHING I posted on my Calendar was automatically also posted on her Calendar, and vice-versa. This was a VERY VERY important capability for us. This was some 3rd-party calendar app that came with the phone; I don't know who created it.

My new Moto G has some version of Google Calendar, and it won't do this.  I can't find her Calendar app on the Play Store anywhere.  It was extremely simple to set up. When you added an event, there was a space to put a person's email address. Then the event would show up on that person's calendar as well as yours.

Can anyone suggest a Calendar app that will do this?

Possible solution: uninstall the Google Calendar from my Moto G, then transfer her Calendar app over from her J3V. Would that work? Please help, thanks.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall Google Calendar app on your devices. Multiple calendars can exists on a device. First I would try to find out the exact app name and package name of the calendar app on the J3V. You can use an app info app like [AppInspector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubqsoft.sec01)

Comment: AFAIK, Google Calendar also allows adding guests by email addresses. This will integrate automatically for Google-based accounts (make sure the Calendar sync is enabled from the Android Settings), but probably need a manual interaction for other email providers/calendar apps by consuming the attached .ics file.